# tymon jwt-auth laravel 5.4 error

Tags: jwt, laravel-5.4

I am getting this error after composer update....
I am using laravel version 5.4.*

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

My providers array

```
`'providers' => [App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
         'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider'

    ],`
```

My alias array

```
 'aliases' => ['View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,
        'JWTAuth' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth',
        'JWTFactory' => 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory'


    ],
```

My composer.json
,

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
```

The error is

```
C:\wamp\www\myproject\app>php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JW
TAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider"
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::sh
are() in C:\wamp\www\myproject\app\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\Providers\JW
TAuthServiceProvider.php on line 122
```

Comment: the `share()` method has been removed in 5.4: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1a1969b6e6f793c3b2a479362641487ee9cbf736

Issues already opened, e.g: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/975

Comment: Thanks to all. I will be testing it today and keep posted

Answer (score 1):

Use dev-master branch. Edit yout composer json file.

```
"require": {
    ...
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-master"
    ...
},
```

and composer update

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a provider in app.php the code is like this:

```
ProviderPath/ProviderName::class,
```

Change this line:

```
'providers' => [App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
         'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider'//this one

    ],
```

to

```
'providers' => [App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class //this one

    ],
```